# Grayscale Morphology

Tags: image-processing

How can I achieve **grayscale** morphological operations on 2D images in Mathematica. With morphology I mean operations like Dilation and Erosion. With grayscale I mean the operations that take images and kernels with scalar values.

The only functions I can find (`Dilation[image,ker]`, `Erosion[image,ker]`,...) only allow binary kernel matrices with values 0 and 1 only.

Is there a built-in function? Or can anyone provide an implementation. Dilation and Erosion are the most important ones, since most others can be implemented by these.

Comment: I may be mistaken here, but I always thought that the definition of the dilation and erosion operators *required* the kernels to be binary. Dilation picks the maximum value of all the image pixels below the 1's in the kernel  for every location the kernel is placed on. Non-binary values would not make sense in this context. Perhaps you are looking for another operation like `ImageConvolve`?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: What you're thinking of, and what Mathematica apparently implements, is a special case of [grayscale morphology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology#Grayscale_morphology) with [flat kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology#Flat_structuring_functions). One can certainly use nonflat kernels in principle.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology#Grayscale_morphology

Comment: Sjoerd, the grayscale morphology operators are less well known, but very important. See the definition in the link Rahul provided. As an example where it is useful: I used it once to find the path of a spherical milling tool, so that a given target surface should (at least) be left. The inverse operation then gave me the actual surface after milling.

Comment: To implement this, the best way is certainly `ImageFilter[]` (which is not a filter, in the meaning of linear and translation invariant ie convolution) that can apply to each pixel wathever function of the its neighborhood.

Comment: This link might be useful talking about Binary and Grayscale Morphological Operators... http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v8i1/features/jankowski/contents/html/Links/index_lnk_4.html

Answer (score 2):

Trying to improve on my comment:

The test image:

```
img=Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/psg1h.png"]
```

[image]

Since `Dilation`...

```
dil = Dilation[img, DiskMatrix[4]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

...can also be written as:

```
fil = ImageFilter[Max[DiskMatrix[4] #] &, img, 4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ImageData[dil] == ImageData[fil]
(* True *)
```

this probably means that a non-binaray `Dilation` can be written as:

```
ker = Table[i j/81, {i, 9}, {j, 9}];
ImageFilter[Max[ker #] &, img, 4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`Erosion` is somewhat more complex. We need two `ColorNegate`-s here:

```
er = Erosion[img, DiskMatrix[4]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
erFil = ColorNegate@ImageFilter[Max[DiskMatrix[4] #] &, ColorNegate@img, 4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ImageData[er] == ImageData[erFil]
(* True *)
```

So, the non-binary `Erosion` would then be:

```
ker = Table[i j/81, {i, 9}, {j, 9}];
ColorNegate@ImageFilter[Max[ker #] &, ColorNegate@img, 4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I must admit I'm working on my intuition here and haven't really checked this against any official definitions of these functions.

Comment: I think (?) it should be `ImageFilter[Max[# + ker] & ...`

Comment: @nikie That doesn't seem to work as replacement of `Dilation`. You could try that with the above example, yielding [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vTAVp.png), which is not the same result.

Comment: I think, though, that the kernel itself may need to be flipped.

Comment: I'm just translating the formulas on the wikipedia page azt linked. Apparently, to get the same result as in binary morphology, the kernel should contain `0` and `-infinity`: `greyKernel = DiskMatrix[4] /. {0 -> -\[Infinity], 1 -> 0};
fil = ImageFilter[Max[# + greyKernel] &, img, 4]`